# Odin cannot add Synaptic Package Manager or Steam

Tags: applications, appcenter, release-odin

It is not available via the AppCenter, and installing it manually results in an app that asks for authentication and then exits.

I wanted to use Synaptic to install Steam, as I had under Elementary OS 5.

Answer (score 1):

In terminal,

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install synaptic
```

Answer (score 0):

Elementary OS is moving towards flatpak packages. It is highly recommended you [install the flatpak version of steam](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.valvesoftware.Steam).

Just open that link and press Install. Then it will open a Sideload screen that will let you install Steam on your system.